# Must a token be verified when Azure App Registration is used for Authorization when securing a Function App

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, authorization, bearer-token

**Here is my setup:**
Azure components I use:

1. App Registration
2. Azure AD
3. Function App (python-code)

I have created an *Azure App Registration* connected with my *Azure AD*. This *App Registration* is then used in my *Azure Function App* to select my *Azure AD* as the identity provider.
This works quite well: When calling a function via a browser the user is redirected to the AD-login and afterwards the Function App gets the bearer token.
This bearer token is decoded in the python code of my functions and the user-assigned roles are checked to contain the role which is needed to execute the function.
Calls to the function app without providing a token, throw a 401.

All in all the functions should be as secure as possible. Only users which are assigned the correct roles in the corresponding *Enterprise Application* should be able to get a result from the function.

**Now to my question(s):**
From a security point of view: is it necessary to validate the provided bearer token (i.e. checking *aud* or *signature* of said token) inside of the python code of my function app?
Or is the token validation implicitly done when registering the app and thus using the Azure AD as Identity Provider?
What are attackers scenarios which could circumvent getting the token from my AD?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**:
I found some links to further explain what I mean by "token validation":

- https://authguidance.com/2017/12/06/jwt-access-token-validation/
- https://www.voitanos.io/blog/validating-azure-ad-generated-oauth-tokens

Now to the question I have:
Is anything of the explained steps done implicitly by Azure, or do I have to write code into my function app which validates the token as described in the links.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK,**

- Authentication is important in-order to show the users are valid to use our applications.

If you don't put restrictions or authentications then the scenario like Hacker can create fake name as you and can see all your data and can misuse it.

#### If you have a requirement in deeper level,

You can put 2-Step Verification, every time we can identify the user is real/valid and has which level of access restriction to use our data.

2 Step Verification = AD Authentication + Role based access restrictions (Authorization)

#### is the token validation implicitly done when registering the app and thus using the Azure AD as Identity Provider?

Azure Active Directory Authentication means retrieving and verifying bearer token.

Authorization level access is the restricting the user in read/write the application data i.e., can be set in AD (implicitly) and also explicitly - application wide level using code configuration to validate key generated internally or Authorization Keys for the Function App Endpoint to see the result.

Even though the Authentication is there for the external users, it doesn't mean full access available to that user with our applications/app data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I was not clear enough when typing my questions. I do 2 things right now: 
1. I configured an AppRegistration for my FunctionApp so that a user who wants to call the a function of the FunctionApp needs to log in. 
2. In the code of the functions in my FunctionApp I access the bearer token, get the assigned roles and make sure that the user has the rules that I want him to have to execute the rest of the function code.
I was wondering if I need to send a verif. request to the AppRegistration in the code of my FunctionApp or is this verif. is done implicitly?

Comment: As you told that the Function App (Registered with Azure AD App Registration & Written Code to verify token, RBAC Auth Level), then the verification meant to be happening implicitly!

Comment: Hello @NoahMueller, do let me know if the information provided helped you in solving your problem?

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT,
as security is very important for our application we decided to go the safest way and implement such a validation. I had the feeling that I was not able to describe my problem in a way for you to answer it properly. I was not certain even with your detailed answers.
Azure vocabulary is tough sometimes... Thanks a lot for your effort!